# Annonymous functions and foreach usage on event-driven code in julia

Tags: julia

I'm currently following Julia for pythonistas notebook by Aurelien Geron (https://github.com/ageron/julia_notebooks) and I'm a bit confused on annonymous functions chapter with the following code:

```
handlers = []

on_click(handler) = push!(handlers, handler)

click(event) = foreach(handler->handler(event), handlers)

on_click() do event
    println("Mouse clicked at $event")
end

on_click() do event
    println("Beep.")
end

click((x=50, y=20))
click((x=120, y=10))
```

Mainly I can't see how `on_click()` gets the `event` from `click()`. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What might not be obvious is how the `handlers` array are filled, namely by applying `on_click()` twice.

```
on_click(handler) = push!(handlers, handler)
```

*defines* a function that adds a handler, whereas

```
on_click() do event
    println("Mouse clicked at $event")
end

on_click() do event
    println("Beep.")
end
```

*calls* this newly defined function twice. The `do` notation hides this a little bit but basically this translates to:

```
push!(handlers, event -> println("Mouse clicked at $event"))
push!(handlers, event -> println("Beep."))
```

What follows when `click()` is called is that the element provided e.g. `(x=50, y=29)` is passed to all handlers using the `foreach` construct.